# CKEditor prevent removing id attribute

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

in `CKEditor` i'm trying to prevent remove `id` attribute from html tags, such as:

```
<p id='hello'>Hello</p>
```

but this configuration of ckeditor dont work and i can't find any other solution about this problem

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
            allowedContent: true,
            autoGrow_onStartup: true,
            extraAllowedContent: '*[id]',
        });
    });
</script>
```

could you help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all using  `allowedContent: true`, and `extraAllowedContent: '*[id]'` makes no sense. The first option disables ACF allowing everything while second one extends it. It makes no sense to allow extra content if everything is allowed already. You should use one of these two options depending whether you want ACF turned on or not.

While pasting HTML like `<p id='hello'>Hello</p>` into source mode and then switching to wysiwyg and back to source will keep the `id` attribute intact (also with your current configuration), you won't get the same result when you copy/paste such element. Please remember that according to HTML specification the `id` attribute has to be unique so you can't have a bunch of `<p id='hello'>Hello</p>` inside editor content area (document). In such a case editor auto-removes the `id` attribute so that it doesn't get duplicated and there is no way to disable it.

If you wanted to identify elements based on same `id` then I would rather suggest using `data-*` attributes or CSS classes instead (they won't get removed during copy/paste). If your requirement is that every element should have `id`, you can use [paste](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-paste) event handler where you simply can check whether element in pasted data has `id` attribute and add it with some random value if it doesn't.

Comment: i'm trying to make simple internal links from content

Comment: Please provide more detailed and technical description of what you are trying to do as the above doesn't help much. It also doesn’t change the fact that `id` has to be unique across whole document so you can’t simply copy/paste bunch of elements with same `id` in CKEditor.